# mysql keeps crashing on docker with the error: [ERROR] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict

Tags: mysql, docker

I have got a problem in my docker with mysql,it is crashing in my docker and keeps restarting and I have to delete the data in order to make it work again.
what can be the reason for this issue?

**error logs:**
[ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3289:for_table || ref_table thread 281472688480272

"Trying to get some variables.

Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.

Query (0): is an invalid pointer

Connection ID (thread ID): 0

Status: NOT_KILLED"

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem and the solution.
**This can happen to VPN / VM users.**

the problem occured because I had changed my network connection since I was using **VPN** so whenever I reconnected to the network it changed my UUID.
and I couldn't connect to mysql that was created in the previous network with the different UUID.

**there are few options to solve this problem:**
1)just go to the VPN settings and find your UUID and copy it, then go to mysql-data and find auto.cnf and replace the UUID.
path: xx/.../mysql-data/auto.cnf
and it should be fine.

2)the better solution is to set your VPN in order to reconnect to your previous profile and not to create a new one.

3)set up a user and login as root user in MySQL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSPIu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I wasn't using a VPN or VM. Deleting the `.docker` folder in my project did it for me.